# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable when iterating through list of tuples and examining the first str from each tuple

Tags: python

I am working on my first program for class - it has four functions, one of them `main()`.

The first function prompts the user for a file name and opens that file. `main()` then prompts the user for a column in that file so that it knows what data to work with.

The second function generates a list of tuples- each tuple a line from that column and it's corresponding date (which is column 0 in the file. The third function is supposed to look at the dates in the tuples in list of tuples from function two and average the data for each month (there are multiple tuples for each month). This is where I run into the error: `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`

Here's my third function:

```
def average_data(list_of_tuples):

    month_int = 2
    values_to_average_int = 0.0
    data_avg_int = 0.0
    average_divisor_int = 1
    list_of_month_average_tuples = []
    val = 0

    for val in list_of_tuples:
        #month_val = int(val[0][5:7])
        if val[0][5:7] == month_int:
        #if month_val == month_int:
            values_to_average_int += val[1]
            average_divisor_int += 1
            print(values_to_average_int)

        else:
            data_avg_float = float(values_to_average_int / average_divisor_int)
            month_yr_date_str = val[0][5:7] + '-' + val[0][:4]
            month_average_tuple = (data_avg_int, month_yr_date_str)
            list_of_month_average_tuples.append(month_average_tuple)
            #list_of_month_average_tuples(data_avg_int, month_yr_date_str) 
            month_int -= 1
            if month_int == 0:
                month_int = 12
            print(list_of_month_average_tuples)
    return list_of_month_average_tuples
```

How do I correct the `TypeError` exception I'm currently getting?

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the tuples and assigning the current tuple to `val`. To access the values in `val` just use one set of brackets, not two because the given tuple is not two-dimensional. `val[5:7]` not `val[0][5:7]`.

Also, you have `val=0` above the aforementioned `for` loop. You shouldn't assign it a value like this - it makes `val` ambiguous.

Read up on the Python `for` loop [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I'm completely stuck at this point. Also, val is supposed to examine something within the tuple so how would it know which string to examine without [0] ?

Comment: @Seth Let's say your tuple is `val = (a,b,c,d,e)`. Then `val[0] == 'a'`, `val[4] == 'e'`. Since `val` refers to a single tuple inside the loop, you only need one dimension of reference.